# How to install D.eval() library in flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

How to install D. eval() library in flex 4.5??

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Close Flex, copy the swc into the libs folder, open flex import the package.

import r1.deval.D;